# Does runtime.LockOSThread allow child goroutines to run in same OS thread?

Tags: go

I understand that in Go, [`runtime.LockOSThread()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) will bind a goroutine to one OS thread and not allow other goroutines to execute in that thread.
Is this also true for child goroutines?

For example:

```
runtime.LockOSThread()
go func() {
    go func() {
        // Do something
    }()
    // Do something
}()
```

Do both of these goroutines execute in a single and exclusive OS thread or only the first one?

Comment: Even though it’s not currently supported, it has [been proposed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-dev/HJcGESXfJfs/X-SBuDkcBwAJ) for a new optional capability. And I have proposed [other use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880262/forcing-goroutines-into-the-same-thread#comment83771359_1928637).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) for `runtime.LockOSThread` says:

> LockOSThread wires **the calling goroutine** to its current operating system thread. Until the calling goroutine exits or calls UnlockOSThread, it will always execute in that thread, **and no other goroutine can**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

This means that if a certain implementation of Go did what you're asking, it would be faulty.

To clarify: if a goroutine had reserved a thread and another goroutine executed on that same thread; that's what would be wrong.

Comment: I'm using version 1.4. I've run the example(now erased) multiple times and is consistent with my conclusion. If the implementation is inconsistent with the documentation, I agree. But I don't see any benefit locking a single go routine to one OS thread if you cannot spawn more controlled goroutines in that thread.

Comment: Maybe `runtime.NumCPU()` returns 1 on your system? Anyhow you should report this bug, including the repro.

Comment: I'm using `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())`. I will report the bug. But I believe the error to be in the documentation because I fail to understand the benefits of lock a goroutine to a OS thread if you do not allow inside concurrency. Even it usage is not clear in doc and can be misinterpreted. It lock the next goroutine created to OS thread or the current one? is not clear at all.

Comment: The goroutine that calls `runtime.LockOSThread()` is the one that's stuck to a thread. If you use the `go ...` from there, the spawned goroutine should _not_ execute on the same thread.

Comment: It is important to keep in mind that `runtime.LockOSThread()` does not prevent other threads from spawning from the context of the thread where the goroutine is running, which means other goroutines can run in the context that shares certain thread-specific data like namespaces, uid, and gid. For more information see: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435

Answer (score 6):

We can check it using pthread.h's `pthread_self`:

```
package main

// #include <pthread.h>
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    ch1 := make(chan bool)
    ch2 := make(chan bool)
    fmt.Println("main", C.pthread_self())
    go func() {
        runtime.LockOSThread()
        fmt.Println("locked", C.pthread_self())
        go func() {
            fmt.Println("locked child", C.pthread_self())
            ch1 <- true
        }()
        ch2 <- true
    }()
    <-ch1
    <-ch2
}
```

On my machine it prints something like this, `main` and `locked` always being sometimes the same, but sometimes different:

```
main 139711253194560
locked 139711219787520
locked child 139711236572928
```

**EDIT** I forgot about GOMAXPROCS. Added, the results are varying now.

Comment: Thank you. I experiment your example putting the lock before the first go and works fine. You can add that example to your answer or allow me to replicate your example to answer my own question.

Comment: @joaonrb At first I forgot about setting GOMAXPROCS. I've edited it now.

Comment: It turns out I was using the runtime.LockOSThread() to late in the code. I used your example to explain the solution to my problem. Thanks.